# Type annotation for Immutable.js Map when passing to Redux reducer

Tags: redux, flowtype, immutable.js

I've been slowly adding Flow type annotations to a small Redux application. However, I'm stuck on adding an annotation for the state in the reducer.

The application in question uses Immutable.js, and the state parameter is an instance of `Immutable.Map`. Try as I might, I can't figure out how to annotate that.

Here is the reducer in question:

```
// @flow
import {List, Map, fromJS} from 'immutable';

type Action = {
  type: string,
  content: mixed
};

export default function(state = Map(), action: Action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'ADD_LINK': {
    let links = state.get('links').push(fromJS(action.content));
    return state.set('links', links);
  }
  case 'UPDATE_FILTER':
    return state.set('filter', fromJS(action.content));
  default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

Any idea how I can add a type annotation for the state as an Immutable.js map? I've tried the following without success, and now I'm stumped:

```
import type { Map } from 'immutable';

export default function (state: Map = Map(), action: Action) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can describe the `state` as the following:

```
export default function(state: Map<string, mixed> = Map(), action: Action)
{
    // ...
}
```

Also, there is a better way to describe the `Action`:

```
export type Action = {
    type: 'ADD_LINK' | 'UPDATE_FILTER'
  , content: mixed
};
```

Now invalid action strings would be detected...

Please note, that to call your function you have to explicitly convert a literal object to `Map`:

```
let res = blah(Map({foo: 'bar'}), {type: 'ADD_LINK', content: 'blah-blah'});
```

Comment: I've recently faced w/ the same problem too and still trying to find an answer to mine question: _The map with an application state usually have limited set of valid keys and consists of nested `Map`s as well. Is there any **better** way to describe it for Flow?_ :)